# How to get data to upload while using plupload

Tags: php, jquery, plupload

Iam using plupload for multiple image uploadings in my site and I wrote code like

```
$(".drag-here").pluploadQueue({
            // General settings
            runtimes : 'html5',                                
            url : '/index.php?ext=events&action=uploadphoto_action',
            max_file_size : '10mb',
            chunk_size : '1mb',
            unique_names : true,
            dragdrop : true,
            multiple_queues : false,
            multi_selection : false,
            max_file_count : 10,
            filters : [
                {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png,jpeg"}                
            ],

            // Specify what files to browse for

            init : {
                FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
                    up.start();                        
                },
                UploadComplete: function(up, files) {
                   $.each(files, function(i, file) {
                        alert(file);
                    });                        
                }
            }
        });
```

but in my 'uploadphoto_action' method if I printing `$_REQUEST` it dosnt give me the files data...where I done mistake

Comment: I hope you implemented like this : http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_FILES` to get the file data.

Comment: Ofcourse I have tried with that also but it printing empty array

Comment: How can I give my custome upload path if iam using my custome upload method..??